# How can I declare the type of a class property?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My code looks like this:

```
interface IConfigService {

    admin: {
        x: number;
    }
}

class ConfigService implements IConfigService {

    admin: admin = null

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

When I try this I get a syntax error saying `could not find symbol 'admin'`.  I was trying to declare it as an array of type `admin`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are writing this in Typescript, consider the following:

```
interface IAdmin {
    x: number;
}

interface IConfigService {
    admins: IAdmin[];
}

class ConfigService implements IConfigService {

    admins: IAdmin[] = null;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ConfigService implements IConfigService {

        private yourLocalVar: admin[]; // now the yourLocalVar variable has type array which contain object elements of admin type

        constructor() {

        }

    }
```